# simple-salesforce: perform a bulk query on a custom object

Tags: query, bulk-api, simple-salesforce

I have seen examples of how to perform a bulk query on a standard object like this:

```
sf.bulk.Opportunity.query(
    "SELECT Id, Account.Name, Name, RecordType.Name, Type WHERE Id = 12345")
```

I have successfully completed queries like this on standard objects. But what I'm looking to do is query a custom object. I'm getting empty responses when I attempt this:

```
sf.bulk.Custom__c.query(
        "Date__c, ID__c, Transactions__c, Volume__c FROM Custom__c"))
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Update: I have updated the simple-salesforce package to the latest edition 1.12.2. Now the query does not return blank but instead returns:

```
SalesforceGeneralError: Error Code Failed. Response content: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: Date__c
```

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT statement was missing in the query. Prior versions return a blank query instead of throwing an error. Anaconda did not have the most updated version of the package, so using conda install installed an old version. Using pip install and selecting the most current version I updated the package and was able to query the custom object using the API endpoint.